# How to pass color as a function parameter in python

Tags: python, function, colors

I've created a function in python as follows:

```
def confidence_ints(df, color):
   time_series_df = pd.DataFrame(df)
   smooth_path = time_series_df.rolling(20).mean()
   path_deviation = time_series_df.rolling(20).std()
   plt.plot(smooth_path, linewidth=2)
   plt.fill_between(path_deviation.index, (smooth_path-2*path_deviation)[0], 
                     (smooth_path+2*path_deviation)[0], color=color, alpha=.1)
   return
```

I would like to call the function multiple times for different dataframes, and plot specific for colors each df.  However, when I call the function using the following code:

```
confidence_ints(dfmel_statsT_HEL, green)
```

I get the following error:

*NameError: name 'green' is not defined*

How do I do this correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
confidence_ints(dfmel_statsT_HEL, 'green')
```

Comment: Thanks. That works! Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Glad to help! Could you mark my answer as accepted?